# How to run gdb with LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: gdb, qemu

I have a program using LD_PRELOAD. The program should be run like
this, "LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libfoo.so qemu -U LD_PRELOAD a.out", if
without gdb.

Here are what I did while running gdb.

`(gdb) set environment LD_PRELOAD=/nfs_home/chenwj/tools/lib/libdbo.so`

`(gdb) file /nfs_home/chenwj/tools/bin/qemu-i386`

`(gdb) r -U LD_PRELOAD bzip2_base.i386-m32-gcc44-annotated input.source 1`

But gdb gave me the error below

`Starting program: /nfs_home/chenwj/tools/bin/qemu-i386 -U LD_PRELOAD bzip2_base.i386-m32-gcc44-annotated input.source 1`

`bash: open "/bin/bash" failed: Permission denied`

`During startup program exited with code 66.`

Any sugguestion appreciated.

Regards, chenwj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GDB` does not invoke your executable directly. Instead, it does

```
bash -c '/nfs_home/chenwj/tools/bin/qemu-i386  -U LD_PRELOAD bzip2_base.i386-m32-gcc44-annotated input.source 1'
```

This is done so that bash takes care of I/O redirection (which you are not using).

My guess is that `/bin/bash` doesn't work when LD_PRELOAD=libdbo.so is in effect, though I don't understand the exact nature of failure.

One way to work around this problem is to create a wrapper executable, implementing `C` equivalent of this:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/nfs_home/chenwj/tools/lib/libdbo.so
exec /nfs_home/chenwj/tools/bin/qemu-i386 "$@"
```

and debug that executable (without setting `LD_PRELOAD`). You'll see an extra `SIGTRAP` when the wrapper `execve()`s the wrapped `qemu-i386`, which you should ignore and `continue`.

Comment: What libdbo.so does is try to be executed before the real __libc_start_main, retrieve data from the bzip2_base.i386-m32-gcc44-annotated, then pass to the real __libc_start_main. It turns out that LD_PRELOAD not only affect qemu-i386 but also the bash invoked by gdb. The error occured since bash want to open some file which it shouldn't (bash is also affected by LD_PRELOAD, and it will execute the __libc_start_main provided by libdbo.so). The solution is quite simple. `set exec-wrapper env 'LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libdbo.so'` will do the trick.